# Reading and printing multiple lists in Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel

I have 3 different columns of data that I am trying to organize and print. The excel file looks like:

[image]

I am trying to read the data into Python and my end goal is to print the data in the following way:

```
Red: tshirt - 32, pants - 16, socks - 1
Blue: flannel - 48, pants - 23, socks - 5
Yellow: tshirt - 12
```

I organized all the columns into their own lists but the part I cannot figure out is how to instruct my program how to organize the items under the color heading since the color column only has 3 values. For example, how can I tell the program that tshirt, pants, and socks are under the red color heading and tshirt is under the yellow color heading? Is there a way to generalize this so it can read and sort this information on other spreadsheets of the same format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, using [`pandas.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html),[`pandas.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and [`pandas.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx',header=None)
df=df.fillna(method='ffill').groupby(0).agg(list)
print(df)


for idx,color in enumerate(df.index):
    line=str(color)+': '
    for cloth,value in zip(df.iloc[idx,0],df.iloc[idx,1]):
        line+=str(cloth)+' - '+str(value)+', '
    print(line[:len(line)-2])
```

Output:

```
df:

                              1            2
0                                           
Blue    [flannel, pants, socks]  [48, 23, 5]
Red       [tshirt, pants, sock]  [32, 16, 1]
Yellow                 [tshirt]         [12]

#Desired Output
Blue: flannel - 48, pants - 23, socks - 5
Red: tshirt - 32, pants - 16, sock - 1
Yellow: tshirt - 12
```

**Edit:**

Using `openpyxl` and [`is_color_like`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.is_color_like.html):

```
import openpyxl as opx
from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
workbook = opx.load_workbook(r'Book1.xlsx', read_only=True)
first_sheet = workbook.worksheets[0]

fstr=''
for i in range(first_sheet.max_row):
    for j in range(first_sheet.max_column):
        if first_sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value!=None:
            s=first_sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value
            if is_color_like(s) and not all(map(str.isdigit, s)):
                fstr+='\n'+s+': '
            elif isinstance(s, int):
                fstr+=str(s)+', '
            else:
                fstr+=s+' - '
            


print(fstr[:len(fstr)-2])
```

Output:

```
Red: tshirt - 32, pants - 16, sock - 1, 
Blue: flannel - 48, pants - 23, socks - 5, 
Yellow: tshirt - 12
```

Comment: Kind of confused, how does this deserve a downvote? Would like an explanation on this downvote please.

Comment: I didn't give the downvote on your answer if this was addressed to me.

Comment: No worries, it wasn't to you ;), plus you can't give downvote until you reputation reaches 125. Thanks for clarifying anyway. It was an on-air commentary to see if the person who made downvote would clarify why. Btw  @scubadiver45, the answer helps you?

Comment: It could have been a 'typo' made in a hurry. It's corrected addressed, rectified & rebalanced now. *Cough.*  If it was something professional I would like to know too since your answer was perfect.

Comment: Oh ok haha I'm really new to stack overflow so not sure how use all of its features yet. I haven't tested the solution yet but it makes sense. However, could you explain how it iterates through the colors? Would you know if it possible to do this in openpyxl? I don't mind using pandas but I'm more comfortable with openpyxl so just wondering if its possible. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, no worries. Thanks for accepting my answer, I just edited it and added a solution with openpyxl, hope it helps you :)! @scubadiver45